# navigation.navigate does not recognize my screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

What the terminal says when I try to bring a video into the application I'm making is that Do you have a screen named "savePost" This is where I am trying to navigate

```
return (
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
        {currentUserObj.currentUser == null ? 
            <Stack.Screen name = "auth" component = {AuthScreen} options = {{headerShown: false}}/>
            :
            <>
              <Stack.Screen name="home" component = {HomeScreen} options = {{headerShown: false}}/>
              <Stack.Screen name="savePost" component = {SavePostScreen} options = {{headerShown: false}}/>
            </>            
        }
    </Stack.Navigator>       
</NavigationContainer>
```

)
}

This is the part where I use navigation.navigate, i tried navigation.push and to navigate without the useNavigation() both did not work.

```
const pickFromGallery = async()=>{
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
        mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Videos,
        allowsEditing: true,
        aspect: [16,9],
        quality: 1
    })
    if(!result.cancelled){
        let sourceThumb = await generateThumbnail(result.uri)
        navigation.navigate("savePost", {source: result.uri, sourceThumb})
    }

}
```

I can put the SavePostScreen code here as well, but I doubt it will do anything, I am just putting the package.json file here.

````
  "name": "academical",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start --dev-client",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^6.2.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.2.3",
    "expo": "^46.0.9",
    "expo-av": "~12.0.4",
    "expo-camera": "~12.3.0",
    "expo-constants": "~13.2.3",
    "expo-image-picker": "~13.3.1",
    "expo-media-library": "~14.2.0",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.16.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.0",
    "expo-video-thumbnails": "~6.4.0",
    "firebase": "^8.10.1",
    "react": "18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "18.0.0",
    "react-native": "0.69.5",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.6.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.12.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.1",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.15.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.18.7",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.4",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  }
}```
````

Comment: In which component are you calling `pickFromGallery` ?

Comment: <View style={{flex:1}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> pickFromGallery()}
                        style = {styles.galleryButton}>
                        {galleryItems[0]==undefined ?
                        <></>
                    : <Image style={styles.galleryButtonImage}
                    source = {{uri:galleryItems[0].uri}}/>
                    }
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>

Answer (score 0):

`savePost` screen will only be accessible if the `currentUserObj.currentUser` is `not null`. If it is `null`, you're basically replacing all the available screens with main screen, and when you'll try to navigate to this screen, react-navigation won't be able to find it. You can basically confirm this by logging the `currentUserObj.currentUser` variable itself.

Comment: I am at the homescreen because it is not null, i am trying to pass from HomeScreen to savePost but even though i can pick a video, i dont see the savePost screen after that